# $f(x,y)= (x^4-y^4)/(x^4+y^4)$ and $ f(0,0)=0 $ show that f is continuous at origin. Using epsilon- delta definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)= (x^4-y^4)/(x^4+y^4)$ and $f(0,0)=0$

show that f is continuous at origin. Using the epsilon- delta definition.

This is all I  know till now:
we have to prove:
$|(x^4-y^4)/(x^4+y^4)| < \epsilon$

we have  $|x| , |y| < \delta$. what should i assume delta to be ?

Answer (score 3):

The given function is not actually continuous at the origin.

If we approach the origin on the line $y = 0$ we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x,0) = 1\neq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* We have $x^4-y^4=(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)$. Let $x=r\cos t,y=r\sin t$. The radii will simplify, and you will get $$\frac{{{{\sin }^2}t - {{\cos }^2}t}}{{{{\sin }^4}t + {{\cos }^4}t}}$$

This gives many different limits depending on the angle you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The function is discontinuous at the origin: To see why take a sequence $x_n = ( \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{2n} )$. Clearly, $x_n \to (0,0) $. However,

$$ f(x_n) = \frac{\frac{1}{n^4} - \frac{1}{16n^4}}{\frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{16n^4}} \to \frac{15}{17} \neq 0 = f(0,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the path $y=mx$.
Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)&=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^4-y^4}{x^4+y^4}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^4-m^4x^4}{x^4+m^4x^4}\\
&=\dfrac{1-m^4}{1-m^4}\\
\end{align}
which is different for different values of $m$. Means if you select different paths to approach to the origin, every time you will get different limits. Obviously this limit does not exist at $(0,0)$.

But to be continuous at $(0,0)$, all you need is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)$.

Since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist, there is no way the function to be continuous at $(0,0)$.